# Como exporto um .apk android no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Toda vez que exporto o aplicativo o google da essa mensagem:

[image: Erro google.]

Mesmo eu mudando o AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.2"
```

Procedimento que estou fazendo:

[image: Procedimento.]

Estou exportando certo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu procedimento está correto, mas o problema é que o Gradle reescreve esses atributos no `AndroidManifest`.

Procure no `gradle.build` do seu módulo principal, pelo seguinte trecho:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Altere o `versionCode` e o `versionName` para o desejado.